# How to migrate AppBundle.php with Symfony4 update

Tags: php, symfony

With the update of Symfony4, AppBundle/ will be abolished and will be under src/.
I have set the following actions in AppBundle.php, how is the best way to migrate?
**Code**
AppBundle.php

```php
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); 

        // Make the container accessible from static methods
        Parameters::setContainer($this->container); 

         // Don't throw an exception when SwiftMailer uses an RFC-violating address(consecutive dots, @immediately preceding dot)
         // Change the regular expression for address checking.
         // (use reflection to change private variables)
        $swiftMimeGrammar = \Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()->lookup('mime.grammar');
        $prop = new \ReflectionProperty('\Swift_Mime_Grammar', '_grammar');
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $_grammar = $prop->getValue($swiftMimeGrammar);
        $_grammar['addr-spec'] = '.*';
        $prop->setValue($swiftMimeGrammar, $_grammar);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html ?

Comment: Create a fresh 4.4 project and you will end up with a src/Kernel.php class which effectively takes the place of AppBundle.php.  How to get from your current code to using src/Kernel.php will depend on many many things.  If you actually have your app working on 4.0 then it might be time to start with a fresh 4.4 project and do some copy/paste/refactoring.  The fact that you are exposing the container as a singleton means you still have plenty of fun ahead of you.  By the way, 4.x still supports AppBundle.  It's just no longer needed.

Comment: @qdequippe Thanks for your comment. I've already confirmed it, and it seems that AppBundle.php only says to remove it.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your comment. I see, it looks good to move as it is. I don't know the reason for "The fact that you are exposing the container as a singleton...", do I need to fix it?

Comment: Using a singleton is not the Symfony way of doing things.  You might want to read the docs on the service container to get an idea of the 'right way'.  Normally, when a bit of code needs either a parameter or a service then you would inject it per the docs.  However, using a singleton can work and obviously it did work for the original app assuming the app itself worked.  So it is not something that has to be 'fixed' as such.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks you. Sure, I'm very confused because the documentation and app methods are so different.